# Run computed after call function in vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, composition

I use vue3 and I wanna set data in vuex and run computed after call API. but unfortunately, the computed run before the `getProfile` function. I use async-await but it doesn't work (I use `console.log` but I get it `undefined`).

```js
    import { defineComponent, ref, computed, reactive, getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'
    import { useStore } from 'vuex'
    export default defineComponent({
      setup() {
        const internalInstance = getCurrentInstance()
        const axios = internalInstance.appContext.config.globalProperties.axios
        const searchDropdown = ref(false)
        let ProfileData = reactive({})
        const store = useStore()
        const showSearchDropdown = () => {
          searchDropdown.value = true
        }
        const hideSearchDropdown = () => {
          searchDropdown.value = false
        }
        const getProfile = () => {
          axios.get('users/profile/')
            .then(profile => {
              store.dispatch('profile/setProfile', profile.data)
            })
        }
        getProfile()
        ProfileData = computed(() => store.state.profile.ProfileData)
    
        console.log(ProfileData.value)
        return {
          searchDropdown,
          showSearchDropdown,
          hideSearchDropdown,
          getProfile,
          ProfileData
    
        }
      }
    })
```

Comment: How did you use async-await? Can you add the code?

Comment: @tho-masn.  i omitted computed and after that I set `ProfileData` before await.
`const getProfile = async() => {
     ProfileData = await axios.get('users/profile/')
        .then(profile => {
          store.dispatch('profile/setProfile', profile.data)
        })
    }`

Comment: You don't have any `async`/`await` in the code. But event if you had it doesn't matter. `axios.get` is async and it take some time to complete. So `ProfileData` will be `undefined` first and will be filled with the data later. Just use `v-if="ProfileData"` in the template (render component only when data arrive)

Comment: @MichalLevý  
its worked. but I changed computed .
    `const profileData = computed(() => store.getters['profile/profileData'])`
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved
I use `watch` and `v-if` in `template` and I omitted async/await

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to accomplice. But you need to initilize your computed property.

Change

```js
ProfileData = computed(() => store.state.profile.ProfileData)
```

to

```js
const ProfileData = computed(() => store.state.profile.ProfileData)
```